# typeError help, plt.scatter reading my .csv as true/false rather than numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, typeerror

I'm following this [article](https://medium.com/@NephilimJs/hi-sowmya-there-seems-to-be-a-data-format-problem-with-your-code-64b631ba75f6), using my own data trying to plot a customers # of orders against their lifetime spend when I get this error:

I've tried removing true/false values from my dataframe and updating relevant packages

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-221045cec1a1> in <module>
      3 y_means = km4.fit_predict(X)
      4 #Visualizing the clusters for k=4
----> 5 plt.scatter(X[y_means==0,0],X[y_means==0,1],s=50, c='purple',label='Cluster1')
      6 plt.scatter(X[y_means==1,0],X[y_means==1,1],s=50, c='blue',label='Cluster2')
      7 plt.scatter(X[y_means==2,0],X[y_means==2,1],s=50, c='green',label='Cluster3')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
   2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]), 0)' is an invalid key```



Update: After following the advice in the comments and changing my plt.scatter to `plt.scatter(X[y_means==0][:,0],X[y_means==0][:,1],`

I receive the error `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key`
````

Comment: You should try it with `plt.scatter(X[y_means==0][:,0],X[y_means==0][:,1],`....

Comment: After that I receive, `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue with trying to use a numpy technique on a pandas.dataframe
I converted it using `X=X.value` and it worked

Comment: can you please try and explain what you mean by x = x.value? thanks

Comment: `X = X.values` maybe not value. Here just take values as an array not used NumPy type.

Answer (score 3):

```
using Your error code here 

y_means = km4.fit_predict(X)
# solution, convert the dataframe to a np.array
#Visualizing the clusters for k=4
X = np.array(X) #that all
plt.scatter(X[y_means==0,0],X[y_means==0,1],s=50, c='purple',label='Cluster1')
plt.scatter(X[y_means==1,0],X[y_means==1,1],s=50, c='blue',label='Cluster2')
plt.scatter(X[y_means==2,0],X[y_means==2,1],s=50, c='green',label='Cluster3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `X = X.values` after importing the dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x)
```